# Need help separating my project. Angularjs+Php+MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs

Im doing a project to display data from mysql, im currently using php and angularjs.

I need to create a table to display the data that im fetching from the mysql but i dont know how is the format, im still new in angular and dont know how controllers, modules and directives work. I was told to create a separate "js" file and put my angular functions there. So i would be using the "php" file only for the connection right?.

I also need to integrate some graphs with the data im fetching, and im planning on use google charts.

I have the following code in php

```
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");   
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');  

//puerto 3306 en caso de requerir
$conn = mysql_connect('iphost', 'user', 'password');
mysql_select_db('bdname', $conn);
$result=mysql_query("Select
  projects.project_name As project_name,
  projects.project_alert,
  If((tasks.task_percent_complete < (((To_Days(CurDate()) -
  To_Days(tasks.task_start_date)) * 100) / (To_Days(tasks.task_end_date) -
  To_Days(tasks.task_start_date)))), _utf8'ATRASADO', _utf8'ALDIA') As Estado
From ((tasks Join
      projects On tasks.task_project = projects.project_id) Join
    users On tasks.task_owner = users.user_id) Join
  companies On projects.project_company = companies.company_id
Where ((tasks.task_end_date < (CurDate() + Interval 10 Day)) Or
    (tasks.task_end_date = 0)) And tasks.task_percent_complete < 100 And
  companies.company_name = _utf8'2017 - Proyectos'      ");


$json = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result))     
{
    $bus = array(
        'proyecto' => $row['project_name'],
        'alerta' => $row['project_alert'],
        'Estado' => $row['Estado'] 
    );
    array_push($json, $bus);
}
$jsonstring = json_encode($json);
echo $jsonstring;
?>
```

and my html to display the data:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Probando select</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"> 
        </script>
    </head>    
    <body>
        <div ng-app="selectApp" ng-controller="selectController">
            <h1>Probando Select dotproject</h1>
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
                <tr style="color:grey">
                    <th>Proyecto</th>
                    <th>Alerta</th>
                    <th>Estado</th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="x in content" >
                    <td>{{x.proyecto}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.alerta}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.Estado}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>    
    <script>
        var postApp = angular.module("selectApp", []);
        postApp.controller("selectController", function($scope, $http) {
            $http.get("selectPrueba.php") 
            .then(function(response) { 
            $scope.content = response.data;       
            });
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

If you guys can tell me which way to go it would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a selectController.js file

```
(function () {
    // ----------------------- selectApp Controller Start -----------------------
    var selectController = function ($scope, $http,) {
        //write code here
        $http.get("selectPrueba.php") 
            .then(function(response) { 
            $scope.content = response.data;       
            });

    selectController.$inject = ['$scope',  '$http'];

    angular.module('selectApp')
            .controller('selectController', selectController);
    // ----------------------- selectApp Controller End -----------------------
}());
```

add this file in html

```
<script src="path/to/selectController.js"></script>
```

check best practice for setup angular project https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-best-practices-directory-structure

Comment: thanks for your help, where you wrote "//write code here", what should in type in there?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by creating the following selectController.js file, with comments below.

```
var app = angular.module('selectApp', []);
app.controller('selectController', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("selectPrueba.php")// aca se consume el JSON que viene de selectPrueba.php
    .then(function (response) {$scope.content = response.data;});
    // acá los datos extraidos en selectPrueba son asignados a la variable content
});
```